# PHP: year when a date occurs the next time

Tags: php, function, date

I need a function that returns the year when a given date (day + month) occurs the first time from now on.

```
function year($day, $month) {
  // ...
  return $year;
}
```

`$day` and `$year` are two-digit numbers

E.g. the given date is '12/25' it should return '2016' (or '16'), but if the date is '02/25' it should return '2017' (or '17').
[Today is August 30, 2016]

Leap years may be disregarded and input doesn't have to be validated.

**EDIT:**
My attempt

```
year($day, $month) {

  $today_day = date('d');
  $today_month = date('m');

  $year = date('y');

  if($month > $today_month) {
    return $year;
  } else if ($month < $today_month) {
    return $year + 1;
  } else {
    if($day >= $today_day) {
      return $year;
    } else {
      return $year + 1;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob A comparison with today, but I think my solution is unnecessarily large

Comment: If you post it others will feel like they are not doing your work for you and may give you an answer

Comment: yes, please post this unnecessarily large solution - we won't break

Comment: you may want to take a look at [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compare the date you are checking against today. If it is today or earlier increment the year of the date. Otherwise do not. Then return that year.

`DateTime()` functionality makes this easy to do.

```
function year($day, $month) {
  $date  = new DateTime("{$month}/{$day}"); // defaults to current year
  $today = new DateTime();
  if ($date <= $today) {
      $today->modify('+1 year');
  }

  return $today->format('Y');
}

echo year(6, 6); // 2017
echo year(12, 12); // 2016
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/631861)**

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate your effort! It was pretty good, but can certainly use some fine tuning. We could reduce the no. of unnecessary if statements.

The function accepts two parameters: month and date. Please be sure we follow the order while calling the function.

In the function, $date is the input date concatenated with the current year.

E.g: **year(12,25)** refers to the year where month is December (12) and day is 25.

year(12,25) would make $date as 2015-12-25.

```
 function year($month, $day) 
 { 
     $date= date('Y').'-'.$month.'-'.$day;
     if (strtotime($date) > time()) {
         return date('y');
     }
     return (date('y')+1);
 }

 echo year(12,25);   // 16

 echo year(2,25);    // 17
```

Now, all we need to do is **check the timestamp of $date with the current timestamp- time()**.

strtotime($date) > time() input date timestamp is more than current timestamp. Which implies this date is yet to come in this year. So, we return the current year **date('Y').**

If the above if is not executed, it's obvious that this date has passed. Hence we return the next year  **date('Y') + 1**.